# Can't parse entities: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 27

Tags: python, aiogram

aiogram
При выполнении кода:

```
async def donate(message):
    await message.answer('Variable: @hhhh123\nNumber\\(OKJ/JPS\\):\n`1111111111`', parse_mode="MarkdownV2")
```

Выдает ошибку: `Can't parse entities: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 27`
Как фиксить?(чтобы было понятнее, `1111111111` создает текст, при нажатии по которому, он копируется в буфер обмена)

Comment: `This happends when your final string have _ or @ or & (when the endpoint has some rules with the string).` из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224362/telegram-bot-cant-find-end-of-the-entity-starting-at-truncated). То есть это из-за `@` у Вас скорее всего.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!